# Workbox seemingly not pre-caching chunks from webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm using Webpack to compile my site and the [Workbox Webpack Plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin) to compile the service worker.

Despite the manifest created by Workbox containing a link to an array of correct chunk names (with the correct hashes for that particular build), the Chrome DevTools don't seem to include the chunks in the precache list (DevTools > Application > Cache Storage).

Here is my configuration for the plugin:

```js
new GenerateSW({
  swDest: '../service-worker.js',
  globDirectory: 'priv/static',
  globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,png,svg,jpg,gif,woff2}'],
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/js.intercomcdn.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9-/_.]*(js|woff)/,
      handler: 'NetworkFirst'
    }, {
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com/,
      handler: 'NetworkFirst',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'google-fonts-stylesheets'
      }
    },
    {
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.gstatic\.com/,
      handler: 'CacheFirst',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'google-fonts-webfonts',
        cacheableResponse: {
          statuses: [0, 200]
        },
        expiration: {
          maxEntries: 5,
          maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, // one year
        }
      }
    },
    {
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/logo.clearbit.com/,
      handler: 'NetworkFirst'
    }, {
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\//,
      handler: 'NetworkFirst'
    }
  ]
})
```

There are warnings in the shell about not needing to include `globDirectory` and `globPatterns`, as Webpack already keeps track of files when its compiling. However, as per the [advice here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#cache_additional_non-webpack_assets), caching of additional assets which Webpack is not aware of should be done through this configuration option. I'm not using `webpack-dev-server`, and I'm serving the site through the [Phoenix](https://phoenixframework.org/) framework.

Looking at the `/service-worker.js` generated from Workbox, it is importing a manifest which *does* contain references to the correct chunks. But they're just not being loaded into the precache in Cache Storage:

```js
importScripts(
  "/js/precache-manifest.94f30538f0c03a9278244eabf2ce9e52.js" // This points to a manifest with the correct chunk names/hashes
);
```

It's probably worth noting that the Network tab in DevTools does say `(ServiceWorker)` in the `Size` column of the chunk names. But how am I to trust this when those scripts don't appear in the Cache Storage?

What's even stranger is if I remove the references to `globDirectory` and `globPatterns`, the Webpack chunk files *do* appear in the Cache Storage. The problem with this, though, is that I have assets that Webpack is unaware of that I want to be precached using Workbox.

Used plugin version is 4.x.x. Later versions of the plugin do not allow params `globDirectory` and `globPatterns`.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2145

Comment: Thanks @JeffPosnick - you were indeed correct.

Comment: @shennan - which version of the workbox webpack plugin are you using? I am using 6.1.2 and AFAIS usage of `globDirectory` and `globPatterns` is forbidden altogether. I am currently struggling with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66818852/using-webpack-to-just-build-service-worker-code-with-workbox-plugin-cannot-sp)

Comment: @shennan - I was able to run your examples with version 4.1.3 (Webpack 4.0.0). Came here while trying to solve [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66818852/using-webpack-to-just-build-service-worker-code-with-workbox-plugin-cannot-sp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Jeff's comment on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2145), this was due to a UI confusion on ChromeDev Tools which paginates the Cache Storage Results.

> If the total number happens to be greater than 50, you'll need to use the arrows to page through entries, 50 at a time.

Here are the aforementioned inconspicuous page buttons:

[image]

Not the best UI IMO.